# Use of Unresolved Identifier 'GMSServices'

Tags: ios, google-maps-sdk-ios

I am using Xcode 7.1 and the deployment target is iOS 9.1. The app is "AreaCalculator" and it was written in Swift. I did following to set up the framework and import the map:

1. $ sudo gem install cocoapods
2. under "AreaCalculator" $ touch Podfile
3. in Podfile I put:

   ```
   source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
   platform :ios, '9.1'
   pod 'GoogleMaps'
   ```
4. $ pod install

   in the terminal:

   [!] Unable to load a specification for the plugin        `/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-try-release-fix-0.1.2`
   Updating local specs repositories
   Analyzing dependencies
   Downloading dependencies
   Installing GoogleMaps (1.10.5)
   Generating Pods project
   Integrating client project

   [!] Please close any current Xcode sessions and use  `AreaCalculator.xcworkspace` for this project from now on.
   Sending stats
   Pod installation complete! There is 1 dependency from the Podfile and  1 total
   pod installed.
5. After that, I selected the AreaCalculator folder in the Navigator
   and    select File\New\File…, then choose the iOS\Source\Objective-C
   File template and created a Bridging file:
   "AreaCalculator-Bridging-Header.h".

   - "#import GoogleMaps/GoogleMaps.h
6. Then I add "GoogleMaps.framework" in "Link Binary With Libraries".
   And both "GoogleMaps.framwork" and ""GoogleMaps.bundle" are in the
   Pods folder.
7. After all those done, in the AppDelegate.swift, I put:

   ```
   import UIKit

   @UIApplicationMain
   class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

       var window: UIWindow?
       let googleMapsApiKey = "MY_GOOGLE_IOS_API_KEY"

       func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
           // Override point for customization after application launch.
           GMSServices.provideAPIKey(googleMapsApiKey)
           return true
       }
   }
   ```

However, the compiler showed me an error "Use of Unresolved Identifier 'GMSServices' ".

I have no idea where I did wrong? Anyone can help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 120):

I have solved the problem by "import GoogleMaps" in the AppDelegate.swift.

Comment: Thank you. 
I had the same issue installing Google Places and Google Places Picker into my project.
I've taken the unprecedented step of sending feedback to the Google team via their website, to highlight the missing line in their sample code.

Comment: thank you. I had to use ***@import GoogleMaps;*** since I am using objective C

Comment: but mine says: No such module 'GoogleMaps'

Comment: temirbrek - run `pod install`

Answer (score 17):

Add this line in AppDelegate.m

```
#import "GoogleMaps/GoogleMaps.h"
```

Answer (score 10):

```
....
#add this line
import GoogleMaps


@UIApplicationMain
@objc class AppDelegate: FlutterAppDelegate {
  override func application(
    _ application: UIApplication,
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?
  ) -> Bool {
  GMSServices.provideAPIKey("YOUR-API-KEY")
    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: self)
    return super.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
  }
}
```

Comment: Please do not post duplicate answers.

Answer (score 10):

I experienced this issue with Flutter and solved it by adding `import GoogleMaps` to the AppDelegate.swift file which is located in ios > Runner>.

Here's what it should look like:

```
import UIKit
import Flutter
import GoogleMaps
```

Comment: Please do not post duplicate answers.

Answer (score 9):

For react native make sure you are importing from above to #if DEBUG mode.

````
Put librarries above #if DEBUG

#import "AppDelegate.h"

#import <React/RCTBridge.h>
#import <React/RCTBundleURLProvider.h>
#import <React/RCTRootView.h>
#import "RNSplashScreen.h" // here
#import <GoogleMaps/GoogleMaps.h>
#if DEBUG
#import <FlipperKit/FlipperClient.h>
#import <FlipperKitLayoutPlugin/FlipperKitLayoutPlugin.h>
#import <FlipperKitUserDefaultsPlugin/FKUserDefaultsPlugin.h>
#import <FlipperKitNetworkPlugin/FlipperKitNetworkPlugin.h>
#import <SKIOSNetworkPlugin/SKIOSNetworkAdapter.h>
#import <FlipperKitReactPlugin/FlipperKitReactPlugin.h>```

Found here -> https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-maps/issues/3453#issuecomment-665475820
````

Comment: Xcode 13.3 Make sure you are not importing under 
#if RCT_NEW_ARCH_ENABLED

Answer (score 4):

**For react native 0.64.1**

Add this line in AppDelegate.m

```
#import <GoogleMaps/GoogleMaps.h>
```

above

```
#ifdef FB_SONARKIT_ENABLED
```

eg:

```
#import <React/RCTLinkingManager.h>
#import "ReactNativeConfig.h"
#import <GoogleMaps/GoogleMaps.h>

#ifdef FB_SONARKIT_ENABLED
#import <FlipperKit/FlipperClient.h>
```

Comment: For React Native 0.70.1 or newer, in AppDelegate.m or AppDelegate.mm place whole #import <GoogleMaps/GoogleMaps.h> with # symbol as well on top of everything but after #import "AppDelegate.h" line. Then go into ios folder in your app directory, then do $pod install and re-run app.

Answer (score -1):

I was facing the same issue, I resolved it by adding this

```
GMSServices.provideAPIKey("GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY")
```

before

```
GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: self)
```

in the `AppDelegate.swift` file.

But make sure to import `GoogleMaps` like this:

```
import GoogleMaps
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HDDUP.png)